# Is there a less verbose SQL query for matching two values against a single list of possibilities?

Tags: mysql, sql

A web site I support executes a MySQL database query that looks like this:

```
SELECT 
   person_per.per_ID 
FROM 
   person_per 
LEFT JOIN 
   person_custom 
ON 
   person_custom.per_ID=person_per.per_ID 
where 
   (per_City='Cathedral City') or 
   (per_City='Cherry Valley') or 
   (per_City='Coachella') or 
   [...and so on for several dozen cities...];
```

The query is supposed to return the set of people who live in any of the specified list of cities.  The query is ugly and verbose, but it works fine.

However, the new request is to modify the query so that it checks not only the person_per.per_City field but also the person_custom.work_City field as well, so that the query returns any one who either lives *or* works in any of the specified cities.

The naive way to do this would be to simply double the number of "or" clauses, like this:

```
SELECT 
  person_per.per_ID 
FROM 
  person_per 
LEFT JOIN 
  person_custom 
ON 
  person_custom.per_ID=person_per.per_ID 
where 
  (per_City='Cathedral City') or 
  (work_City='Cathedral City') or 
  (per_City='Coachella') or 
  (work_City='Coachella') or 
  [...and so on for several dozen cities...];
```

But I'd like to avoid doing it that way if possible, because the only thing worse then a 20-line SQL query containing the entire list of city-names is a 40-line SQL query containing the entire list of city-names *twice*.  That query would be (even more) difficult to write and maintain.

So, is there a way to phrase this query-on-two-columns such that each city's name only appears once in the query?  (I know I could create an SQL table of city names, but I'd rather not modify the applications' set of SQL tables if possible, so I'd prefer a solution that modifies only the SQL query itself)

Comment: You ought to take a look at the [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) comparison operator.

Comment: I think `('Cathedral City' in (per_city, work_city)) or (..` would be slightly better. Can you extract the specified cities into a table?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: That would be terribly index unfriendly in MySQL; better to use `per_City IN ('Cathedral City', 'Coachella', ...) OR work_City IN ('Cathedral City', 'Coachella', ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use the "in" operator:

```
SELECT 
  person_per.per_ID 
FROM 
  person_per 
LEFT JOIN 
  person_custom 
ON 
  person_custom.per_ID=person_per.per_ID 
where 
  per_City in ('Cathedral City','Coachella', 'city1', 'city2', ...) OR 
  work_City in ('Cathedral City','Coachella', 'city1', 'city2', ...)
```

Comma seperated strings could be easily build up with every programing language, so you shouldn't have to much work on this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `IN` operator to check if a value is in a list of other values, so the first query would be simplified to:

```
   SELECT person_per.per_ID
     FROM person_per 
LEFT JOIN person_custom USING(per_ID)
    WHERE per_City IN ( 'Cathedral City', 'Cherry Valley', 'Coachella', ... )
```

For the second query I would recommend either storing the list of cities in a table or a variable to reduce duplication. The table version of the query would look something like:

```
   SELECT person_per.per_ID
     FROM person_per 
LEFT JOIN person_custom USING(per_ID)
    WHERE per_City  IN ( SELECT cities_City FROM cities )
       OR work_City IN ( SELECT cities_City FROM cities )
```

Comment: The variable approach is not available in MySQL.

Comment: @eggyal Actually it is, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Comment: If per_City is in the person_per table, this answer is ok.  If it's in the person_custom table it's not.  Filtering on a left joined table in the where clause causes the query to behave with an inner join.  To get around that, the filtering has to be moved to the join clause.

Comment: @Oz.: Whilst MySQL has user variables, they cannot be used to store a list for comparison in the manner that you describe in your answer.